# Conditionally run postcss plugin in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, amp-html, bootstrap-vue, postcss

I am trying to implement [AMP](https://amp.dev/) in a Vue Bootstrap Nuxt.js(~2.12.2) project.

The AMP validation was failing because of the use of `!important` rules in Bootstrap's styles.

I was able to find [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@buddye/postcss-remove-important) postcss plugin in order to remove `!important` rules from styles.

I was able to execute this successfully using:

```js
postcss: {
  plugins: {
  '@buddye/postcss-remove-important': {},
  cssnano: { preset: 'default' },
  },
},
```

The problem is that I want to execute this only for a specific scss file, amp custom styles, and not globally.

I've tried the following:

```js
plugins: loaderContext => {
    if (/amp-custom.scss$/.test(loaderContext.resourcePath)) {
        return {
            '@buddye/postcss-remove-important': {},
            cssnano: { preset: 'default' },
        };
    }
    
    return { cssnano: { preset: 'default' } };
},
```

Unfortunately this produces some errors and I can't figure out why

[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uTBD.png)

[image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieM1a.png)

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this or an alternative solution for removing `!important` rules from Bootstrap?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you tried googling the error?

Comment: @kissu Yes I did. As my knowledge about postcss is limited I couldn't find something that I could use.